# DevOps URL Default Project Collection

Tags: azure-devops, devops

If I have a DevOps URL of https://companydevops.net and I have 3 project collections.  Project Collection A, Project Collection B and Project Collection C, how can I get Project Collection A to appear at the base DevOps URL of https://companydevops.net?  Right now the base DevOps URL will automatically go to Project Collection C.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Devops Server automatically redirects to the most frequently used collection when you visit the Server's default url.

As of this time, however, it is not supported to set a specific collection when you visit the Server's default url. You can add the name of the collection to the default URL, as in the following example, for quick access.

```
https://companydevops.net/{collection}
```